# IDE is wanting to convert my Int into a boolean? and one of my methods says it cannot be applied

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am having issues. it's wanting to change int len into a boolean? And there is some issue with addNode method.
Not Quite sure what else to add there is this little box yelling at me about adding some more details.
I have all the imports needed.

```
public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {


    private HashMap<String, ClassNode> classes = new HashMap<String, ClassNode>();


    @Override

    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        return findClass(name);

    }


    @Override

    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        ClassNode node = classes.get(name.replace('.', '/'));

        if (node != null)

            return nodeToClass(node);

        else

            return super.findClass(name);

    }


    public final void addNode(String name, ClassNode node) {

        classes.put(node.name, node);

    }


    private final Class<?> nodeToClass(ClassNode node) {

        if (super.findLoadedClass(node.name) != null)

            return findLoadedClass(node.name);

        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);

        node.accept(cw);

        byte[] b = cw.toByteArray();

        return defineClass(node.name.replace('/', '.'), b, 0, b.length,

                getDomain());

    }


    private final ProtectionDomain getDomain() {

        CodeSource code = new CodeSource(null, (Certificate[]) null);

        return new ProtectionDomain(code, getPermissions());

    }


    private final Permissions getPermissions() {

        Permissions permissions = new Permissions();

        permissions.add(new AllPermission());

        return permissions;

    }
    private HashMap<String,URL> resources = new HashMap<String,URL>();
    public final void addResource(String name,URL url){

        resources.put(name, url);

    }
    protected URL findResource(String name) {

        if (getSystemResource(name) == null){

            if (resources.containsKey(name))

                return resources.get(name);

            else

                return null;

        }else

            return getSystemResource(name);

    }

    public void loadClassesFromJar(File jar) throws IOException {

        ZipFile jf = new ZipFile(jar);

        ZipEntry e;

        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = jf.entries();

        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {

            e = entries.nextElement();

            if(e.isDirectory())

                continue; //skip directories, as the file names contain the slashes

            InputStream in = jf.getInputStream(e);

            if (e.getName().endsWith(".class")) {

// reads the class

                ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(in);

                ClassNode cn = new ClassNode();

                reader.accept(cn, ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG

                        | ClassReader.SKIP_FRAMES);

//add the class to our node list

                addNode(e.getName(), cn);

            } else {

//write the resource to a temporary file

                File tmp = File.createTempFile("06loader", "dat");

                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(tmp);

                byte[] b = new byte[1024];

                int len;

                while (len = in.read() >= 0) {

                    fout.write(b, 0, len);

                }

                fout.close(); // flushes and closes the file output stream

                addResource(e.getName(),tmp.toURI().toURL());

                tmp.deleteOnExit(); // delete the file once java closes

            }

        }

        jf.close(); // close the jar file

    }

}
```

Comment: "Not Quite sure what else to add there is this little box yelling at me about adding some more details."  <- How about **more details**? Instead just saying "here is some issue with addNode method" tell us what issue it is. Wrong output? Does it not compile? Any error message? Writing a good question isn't rocket science

Comment: The addNode error is saying it cannot be applied

Comment: `InputStream::read()` does not return *length*. It reads and returns **a single byte of data**.

Comment: How do I fix addNode()? its still saying not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of this line of code:

```
while (len = in.read() >= 0) {
```

It should be:

```
while ((len = in.read()) >= 0) {
```

EDIT: As @Johnny Mopp said, it's a precedence issue and not an equality vs assignement issue.

Comment: Or, it's a precedence issue. `while ((len = in.read()) >= 0) {`

Comment: @Holger, yes, but his version is also in the original code.

Comment: @MProkhorov: I know, but it’s not very helpful to only tell how to fix a syntax error when there is a big obvious semantic error that will hit the OP right after fixing the compiler error.